Sphinx documenting classes with "autoclass", but not with "automodule"
I have looked at all of the similar questions that were suggested when posting this but none of them helped me.
I am trying to create docs for a library and I cannot get .. automodule:: to work. I can, however, get .. autoclass:: to work for a single class inside the module.
This is the structure of my directory (cleaned up to only include the relevant parts):
.
├── docs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── build/
│   ├── make.bat
│   └── source
│       ├── _static
│       ├── _templates
│       ├── conf.py
│       └── index.rst
├── pandaprosumer2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mapping
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   └── generic.py

So in docs/source/index.rst, I would like to have:
Pandaprosumer
===================================

A Python library based on Pandapower and Pandapipes for modelling energy control systems

.. automodule:: pandaprosumer2.mapping
    :members:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

But, the results looks like this:

If I remove the .. automodule::, and instead supply .. autoclass::, like this:
Pandaprosumer
===================================

A Python library based on Pandapower and Pandapipes for modelling energy control systems

.. autoclass::  pandaprosumer2.mapping.GenericMapping
    :members:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

It works, and looks like this, so I know that it is able to find the class:

So, why does it work when using .. autoclass::, but not with .. automodule::?
Extra information
Contents of docs/source/conf.py:
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))

project = 'a'
copyright = '2024, a'
author = 'a'
release = '0.1'

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
              'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
              'sphinx.ext.napoleon',]

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = []



# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']

autosummary_generate = True

Contents of pandaprosumer2/mapping/__init__.py:
from .generic import GenericMapping

Contents of pandaprosumer2/mapping/generic.py (simplified):
"""
This module defines the BaseMapping and ElementWiseMapping classes for mapping controllers in PandaProsumer.
"""

import numpy as np

from .base import BaseMapping


class GenericMapping(BaseMapping):
    """
    Generic mapping between controllers.
    """

    def __init__(self, prosumer=None, initiator=None, initiator_column=None, responder=None, responder_column=None,
                 order=None, application_operation="add", weights=None, index=None):
        """
        Initializes the GenericWiseMapping.

        :param prosumer: The prosumer object
        :param initiator: The initiating controller
        :param initiator_column: The column in the initiating controller
        :param responder: The responding controller
        :param responder_column: The column in the responding controller
        :param order: The order of mapping application
        :param application_operation: The operation to apply (default: "add")
        :param weights: Weights for the mapping
        :param index: The index of the mapping
        """
        super().__init__(prosumer, initiator, initiator_column, responder, responder_column, order, index)
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return "ElementWiseMapping"

    def _validate(self):
        """
        Validates the generic mapping.
        """
        super()._validate()

    def map(self, initiator_controller, responder_controller):
        """
        Applies the element-wise mapping between the initiator and responder controllers.

        :param initiator_controller: The initiating controller
        :param responder_controller: The responding controller
        """
        pass


Results of building using .. autoclass::  pandaprosumer2.mapping.GenericMapping (make clean; make html, executed from docs/):
Removing everything under 'build'...
Running Sphinx v7.3.7
making output directory... done
[autosummary] generating autosummary for: index.rst
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
writing output... 
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 1 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
copying assets... copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
done
writing output... [100%] index
generating indices... genindex py-modindex done
highlighting module code... 
writing additional pages... search done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in build/html.

Results of building using .. automodule:: pandaprosumer2.mapping (make clean; make html, executed from docs/):
Removing everything under 'build'...
Running Sphinx v7.3.7
making output directory... done
[autosummary] generating autosummary for: index.rst
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
writing output... 
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 1 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
copying assets... copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
done
writing output... [100%] index
generating indices... genindex done
highlighting module code... [100%] pandaprosumer2.mapping.generic
writing additional pages... search done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in build/html.

I am totally stumped here, I cannot figure out why it will work for individual classes, but not for the module

I think it should work if you use the imported_members option on automodule.
